# Display total number of items for each of defined type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server:

**Item**:

```
    Id int [PK]
    Name varchar
    TypeId int [FK -> ItemType.Id]
```

**ItemType**:

```
    Id int [PK]
    ItemTypeName varchar
```

I need to read how many `Items` belongs to each of defines `ItemType`, so the result table should look like this:

```
Item Type | Items Count |
----------+-------------+
Type A    |  55         |
Type B    |  21         |
Type C    |  0          |
Type D    |  0          |
```

What I tried so far is this query:

```
select
    ItemType.ItemTypeName as [Item Type],
    count(*) as [Items Count] 
from 
    ItemType
inner join 
    Item on Item.TypeId = ItemType.Id
group by 
    ItemType.ItemTypeName
```

but it only shows `Item Type` for which at least 1 `Item` exists, while I need to display all `Item Types` that are defined, even if there are no `Items` of that type.

How to modify this query to get the result that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `left join`, but you need to fix the `count()` as well:

```
select it.ItemTypeName as [Item Type],
       count(i.TypeId) as [Items Count] 
from ItemType it left join
     Item i
     on i.TypeId = it.Id
group by it.ItemTypeName;
```